# Logical statement for datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime, pandas-loc

I am encountering the following error when I use `df.loc`. I have a parameter s which is datetime64[ns], I have dataframe with two of the column MDT1 and MTD2, which is also datetime64[ns] type. When I use the following statement using df.loc

```
s= df_1x2['date'].astype (str)+'-'+ df_1x2['Time'].astype(str)
s = pd.to_datetime(s)
df_1x2.loc[(s>df_1x2['MDT1'])&(s<df_1x2['MDT2']),'Morning']= s
```

The last line of the code shows me the following error in Jupyter Notebook

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

However, when I run second time, it works as expected. It was just that the first run in Jupyter Notebook got me the error.

Below is the link to download the sample data file:

[Click here to download the sample data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L7gcLrfBML3symS7KwCqbYoXvVUevG4M/view?usp=sharing)

Below is the code:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).astype(str)+' '+df['Time.1'].astype(str)+':00'
df['Matchdate'] = pd.to_datetime (s)

d =np.reciprocal(df_1x2[['Home','Draw','Away']].astype(float))

df_1x2['Margin'] = d.sum(axis = 1)-1
df_1x2['Open_DT'] = df_1x2['date'].astype (str)+'-'+ df_1x2['Time'].astype(str)
df_1x2['Open_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1x2['Open_DT'])
df_1x2['Open_DT1'] = df_1x2.groupby(['Match','Odds_Type'])['Open_DT'].transform(min)
s = df_1x2['Open_DT'] == df_1x2['Open_DT1']
df_1x2.loc[s,'Open'] ='Opening'


df_1x2['Current_DT'] = df_1x2['date'].astype (str)+'-'+ df_1x2['Time'].astype(str)
df_1x2['Current_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1x2['Current_DT'])
df_1x2['Current_DT1'] = df_1x2.groupby(['Match','Odds_Type'])['Current_DT'].transform(max)
sc = df_1x2['Current_DT'] == df_1x2['Current_DT1']
df_1x2.loc[sc,'Current'] ='Current'
df_1x2.loc[df_1x2.Open == 'Opening','Current']='Opening'

df_1x2 ['morning Date'] = pd.Timestamp.today()
Time1 = '08:00:00'
Time2 = '11:00:00'
s = df_1x2['date'].astype (str)+'-'+ df_1x2['Time'].astype(str)
s = pd.to_datetime(s)
df_1x2.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)

df_1x2 ['morning Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1x2 ['morning Date']).dt.date
df_1x2['MDT1'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1x2['morning Date'].astype(str)+' '+Time1)


df_1x2['MDT2'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1x2['morning Date'].astype(str)+' '+Time2)

df_1x2 .reset_index(drop= True, inplace = True)



df_1x2.loc[(s>df_1x2['MDT1'])&(s<df_1x2['MDT2']),'Morning']= s
```

How can I rectify it?

Comment: Can you copy paste `df_1x2`

Comment: @wwnde do you mean entire dataframe?

Comment: Just the head would do if you haven't found a solution

Comment: I will upload the csv file paste the code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying an entire series `s` to a filtered dataframe column. I think it is easier to just use `mask` or `np.where` instead of `.loc`:

```
df_1x2['Morning'] = df_1x2['Morning'].mask((s > df_1x2['MDT1']) & (s < df_1x2['MDT2']), s)
```

or `np.where`:

```
df_1x2['Morning'] = np.where((s > df_1x2['MDT1']) & (s < df_1x2['MDT2']), s, df_1x2['Morning'])
```

---

If the column doesn't exist yet, then use:

```
df_1x2['Morning'] = np.where((s > df_1x2['MDT1']) & (s < df_1x2['MDT2']), s, np.datetime64('NaT'))
```

`.loc` would be okay for this use case if you were assigning a single value like `10` rather than a series that has a longer length than your filtered dataframe.

---

The issue is that you `reset_index()` after defining `s`, which means it is not comparable to your dataframe:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).astype(str)+' '+df['Time.1'].astype(str)+':00'
df['Matchdate'] = pd.to_datetime (s)

d =np.reciprocal(df_1x2[['Home','Draw','Away']].astype(float))

df_1x2['Margin'] = d.sum(axis = 1)-1
df_1x2['Open_DT'] = df_1x2['date'].astype (str)+'-'+ df_1x2['Time'].astype(str)
df_1x2['Open_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1x2['Open_DT'])
df_1x2['Open_DT1'] = df_1x2.groupby(['Match','Odds_Type'])['Open_DT'].transform(min)
s = df_1x2['Open_DT'] == df_1x2['Open_DT1']
df_1x2.loc[s,'Open'] ='Opening'


df_1x2['Current_DT'] = df_1x2['date'].astype (str)+'-'+ df_1x2['Time'].astype(str)
df_1x2['Current_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1x2['Current_DT'])
df_1x2['Current_DT1'] = df_1x2.groupby(['Match','Odds_Type'])['Current_DT'].transform(max)
sc = df_1x2['Current_DT'] == df_1x2['Current_DT1']
df_1x2.loc[sc,'Current'] ='Current'
df_1x2.loc[df_1x2.Open == 'Opening','Current']='Opening'

df_1x2 ['morning Date'] = pd.Timestamp.today()
Time1 = '08:00:00'
Time2 = '11:00:00'

########### I moved s from here...........

df_1x2.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)

df_1x2 ['morning Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1x2 ['morning Date']).dt.date
df_1x2['MDT1'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1x2['morning Date'].astype(str)+' '+Time1)


df_1x2['MDT2'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1x2['morning Date'].astype(str)+' '+Time2)

df_1x2 .reset_index(drop= True, inplace = True)

########### .........to here. 
##### Resetting the  index after defining s, means you can no longer compare directly to your dataframe as s has a different index than your dataframe now.

s = df_1x2['date'].astype (str)+'-'+ df_1x2['Time'].astype(str)
s = pd.to_datetime(s)


df_1x2.loc[(s>df_1x2['MDT1'])&(s<df_1x2['MDT2']),'Morning']= s
```

Comment: Hi @David Erickson, Unfortunately, the column "Morning" does not exist prior to this step and hence I got the error too. I will attach the csv file that contain the data

Comment: @Zephyr what is the alternative result, outside of your condition? What you have just mentioned is your issue. You cannot add a column that is based of a filtered dataframe with a condition to a dataframe, because the length is unequal. See my updated answer if for example the alternative result is `np.nan`.

Comment: Dear David, Thanks. I will try with np.where. Anyway, I edit my question which now include the code and sample data file.

Comment: @Zephyr what should be the alternative in the `'Morning'` column if the condition `s > df_1x2['MDT1']) & (s < df_1x2['MDT2'])` is not met? Should it be `NaN`?

Comment: yes. Nan. I just edited your answer to keep the datetime format as NaT by replacing np.datetime64('NaT')

Comment: @Zephyr Thank you, if this works for you kindly accept as solution; otherwise, let me know what went wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still gave me the same error
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: I think it worked after two fresh run. Thanks a lot. It means I still can apply df.loc but the index give me problem after resetting.

Comment: Thanks a lot David.